# Error "unknown address family 10" in roslaunch's ProcessMonitor

Tags: ros, roslaunch, installation, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I wanted to switch from fuerte to groovy on my virtual machine.
After I have successfully compiled all ros_comm packages, I started roscore, but it terminates at startup with the error message:

unknown address family 10

in the roslaunch/pymon.py.

The system is a custom Linux system (compiled with openembedded) and Python 2.7.3.
NB: As it a custom Linux system, I did not use rosdep to resolve the system dependencies, but tried to resolve it manually.

Googling for the error above did not give a valuable hint what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone have a clue?

The full logfile is at http://pastebin.com/mxNkHBHS.

Lukas Bulwahn
BMW Car IT GmbH
Petuelring 116
D-80809 Muenchen
Germany
Mail: lukas.bulwahn@bmw-carit.de
Web: http://www.bmw-carit.de
BMW Car IT GmbH
Geschäftsführer: Harald Heinecke
Sitz und Registergericht: München HRB134810

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51594/error-%22unknown-address-family-10%22-in-roslaunch%27s-processmonitor/) by [Lukas Bulwahn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3627/lukas-bulwahn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Groovy seems to require python with IPv6 support in constrast to the previous versions (fuerte, electric, ...).
After installing python with IPv6 support (--enable-ipv6), the issue was resolved.

---

Originally posted by [Lukas Bulwahn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3627/lukas-bulwahn/) with karma: 61 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does your Python have IPv6 support? A quick check in iPython with

```
In [1]: import socket

In [2]: socket.AF_INE
socket.AF_INET   socket.AF_INET6  

In [2]: socket.AF_INET6
Out[2]: 10
```

implies that address family 10 is IPv6.

This [Google Group Posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gevent/2uaMnDgVsEo) seems to imply that you may get that error if your Python isn't compiled with IPv6 support, which could be the case given you have a custom embedded Linux install.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3